# Excel or VBA - populate a drop down list from a dynamic column in another sheet with no duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know if this is even possible, but I am trying to do a couple of things that require me to populate drop down lists, and a normal cell by cell list, based on the items in a column on another sheet. I know how to do this with a regular column, but the column I want to use changes length and has many duplicate values in it, as it is an inventory of sorts.

So on this sheet, in C5,

[image]
that value should be able to be selected from a drop down list based on the contents of column B in the second sheet, but also without having to scroll through duplicates. 
 [image]

I am happy to use either VBA or general excel formulas to achieve this. I am also aware that I don't think I have explained this very well so please feel free to prompt me for more information as required.

Comment: Are you familiar with *VBA* ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent   I am indeed. Do you think that is the best way to do it? Can you give me some guidance on how to do it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start.  I assume the the list of items is in *Sheet2* somewhere from **B1** through **B1000**.  It's O.K. if the range is only partially filled *(adjust the 1000 to suit your needs)*.

The code scans this list and builds a DV string.  The Data Validation is then applied to *Sheet1* cell **C5**:

```
Sub setupDV()
    Dim rSource As Range, rDV As Range, r  As Range, csString As String
    Dim c As Collection

    Set rSource = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B1000")
    Set rDV = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5")
    Set c = New Collection
    csString = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In rSource
        v = r.Value
        If v <> "" Then
            c.Add v, CStr(v)
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                If csString = "" Then
                    csString = v
                Else
                    csString = csString & "," & v
                End If
            Else
                Err.Number = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    On Error GoTo 0

    'MsgBox csString

    With rDV.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=csString
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this  - brill! As a relatively VBA newbie, how can I get this code to run regularly - such as every time column B: changes? or every time cell C5 is clicked into?

Comment: sorry, silly question! I have now pulled my head back into today and done that!